# Are there any polyprotic acids where Ka2 is greater than Ka1?

Tags: acid-base

My chemistry textbook says that in the ionisation of a polyprotic acid with Ka1, Ka2 and so on, 'the first Ka is usually the largest.' I took the word 'usually' to mean that there are exceptions to the rule, but I haven't been able to find any cases where Ka2 is greater than Ka1.

Comment: That's a really odd statement. In my experience, they're *always* numbered in decreasing order of numerical value (increasing order of $\mathrm p K_\mathrm a$). I'm curious to see if anyone comes up with an exception to this rule.

Comment: How do you know which proton is the first? No, it goes the other way around: the largest Ka **is** the first, because that proton is naturally the first to react. It can't be otherwise.

Comment: -sigh- the statement doesn't make much sense to me either, but I'm hoping someone will come up with a case where the second dissociation constant is greater. I recently lost a percentage in an exam for answering according to the textbook and saying Ka1 is 'usually' greater than Ka2, rather than 'always.'

Comment: @IvanNeretin What about a hypothetical molecule where the loss of the first proton facilitates the loss of the second proton?

Comment: @DHMO I don't see how's that possible, but let's assume it is. Well, then these two protons would react together and effectively have the same pKa.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Ivan. Ka1 and Ka2 are just labels. They don't carry any information. Which one is most acidic? The one that is larger. It just intuitively makes sense let the largest one be Ka1. It's an exam question that doesn't really require any *understanding* of the subject.

Comment: One cannot dissociate the second proton without dissociating the first proton therefore, *ipso facto*, the first proton must dissociate first and therefore, the Ka1 for the first dissociation must be larger than that for the second. If the second proton were to have a Ka greater than that of the first then it would be the first proton to dissociate and not the second.  So, by *definition*, the first Ka is the largest. Strike "usually"  and substitute "by definition". There are no exceptions to a rule which defines itself.

Comment: The only possible exception that I could think of is some compound where losing a second proton after losing a first is easier. This could possibly happen due to the first deprotonation causing the second one to participate in resonance. I don't know if the extra stability from resonance could be more important than the formal charge on the compound, though.

Comment: @DHMO You're right! It works exactly like that and I read about an example, long time ago but maybe I'll find it.